# Set origin to geometry center

Tags: geometry

I would like to center the origin on the geometry. How can I do that ?
I've tried with 'Origin to Geometry' but it doesn't seems to work correctly. Indeed, on the screenshot, we can see the origin is not exactly centered along the Z axis.

[image: screenshot]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after apply the  'Origin to Geometry' you must be change the center to "bounds Center".. here a Image:

[image]

Comment: How do you access that left panel?

Comment: that is the tool panel  (enable after press the T key) https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html.... after you apply the 'origin to geometry" you can see that in the tool panel

Answer (score 11):

1. Switch to **Edit Mode**, select all elements, make sure the current Pivot Point type is set to *Bounding Box Center*, or simply press <kbd>,</kbd> (comma), <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*;
2. Switch back to **Object Mode**,<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Object to 3D Cursor*.

Answer (score 6):

The way *origin to geometry* works is it moves the origin to the *average location of all vertices*.  So since your mesh has more vertices on the top than the bottom, the z-axis position of the new origin point will be closer to the top than the bottom.

To fix this, simply go into edit mode, select the eight vertices at the corners of the bounding box (I am assuming your model has some x-depth thickness, if not just select the four corners), and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *cursor to selection*.  Then go into object mode and select *origin to 3D cursor*.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the geometry is not centered either.

Look closely at the grid:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I speak about Z axis (top-bottom). I would like to have the origin at the middle height of my model. I can move my model to be centered in height to the axis but it change nothing: the origin move with the model too.

Comment: You can move the mesh independently of the origin while in edit mode.