# How do I reset the origin placement?

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut, origin

The origin (or the small orange dot, if that's even the origin but I'm going to call it that) use to be placed always in the center of the selected shape, when I pressed the comma key, the view would always center to the current selected part(s).

Now I must have hit some key by accident and the origin is now always at the center of the model (where the three axis cross), I looked it up and found out that you could press CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+C for a menu that lets you move the origin, but that set the origin for the whole object, not for the faces seperatly like it used to be. I also tried resetting the preferences and uninstalling(!!) blender which for some reason didn't work!

Is there some shotcut to undo that? Or at least some option file I can get rid of unaffected by the uninstall?

Comment: related [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24078/set-origin-to-geometry-center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24078/set-origin-to-geometry-center)  [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin/14296#14296](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin/14296#14296)

Comment: It would help if you include screenshots of the objects which you have. Origin of the object can be set to some arbitrary faces only if you select those in Edit mode, snap 3d Cursor to them and choose in Object mode origin to cursor, Numpad period button will center on selection regardless of its origin.

Comment: That doesn't solve my actual problem, if it were only about getting the camera right I could simply turn the current view. My problem is that I can't quickly snap the camera to a selected part without these extra steps as the orange dot is now locked at the center of the object. Before the mishap it was always in the center of the current selected part by default.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've selected another pivot mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it wasn't even the origin's fault but more like the 3D view center.

I must have accidently pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad period</kbd> which permanently locks the 3D view center to the selected object (therefore <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> wouldn't work either) which can be unlocked either by removing the lock in the properties panel (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>, in the View rollout) or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad period</kbd>.

What I thought to be the origin must have been the face's center, which when selected, looks similar.