# Set multiple origins to geometry?

Tags: origin

I have lets say 5 individual vertexes objects with the origin all set to the centre of the screen. How could I set each vertex to the geometry of each vertex?

Comment: An object cannot have more than one origin. If they are different objects then you can do what you want (read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object). If what you need is to set different points to rotate a single object based on different axes you can set empties in the place of those vertices and use those to rotate, scale, or whatever other purposes you need, by using constraints.

Comment: Sorry, I ment 5 Indiviaul vertexes that are their own object.

Comment: So you mean 5 objects, each object contains its own mesh(with vertices). And there are 5 vertices on separated meshes you chosen. You want them as their parent object origins?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24078/set-origin-to-geometry-center and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin/14296#14296

Comment: and perhaps  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134440/shortcut-for-setting-origin-to-vertex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.79, in object mode, with all objects selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will send the origins of all the objects to their geometry simultaneously.

in 2.8, until you set a personal shortcut, it's available only through the header > Object > Set Origin menu.

Or, Enable the shipped add-on '3D Viewport Pie Menus' > 'Origin Pie'.. which has the advantage of working in Edit Mode. That lets you set the origin to a selection of the geometry.

Comment: Strange, It wasnt working before now it does..?? Thanks !

Comment: ..@Knuckles209cp I think I vaguely remember a time when it didn't work, too